# find sum of all the positive even numbers less than or equal to the given number

Tags: java

I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
   public int sum(int n)
   {

   }
```

What do you do? I watched a couple of youtube videos but it did not help.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  You need to put a little more effort this.  Here take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: You should start by reading some tutorials about basic operations in java before asking the people here to create code for you

Comment: **youtube videos**? really? with kittens and stuff?

Answer (score 6):

The sum of values up to m is m * (m + 1) / 2),  so the sum of evens is double the sum of values up to n/2.

You can calculate it as follows

```
evensum = 2 * n/2 * (n/2 + 1) / 2;
```

or

```
evensum = n/2 * (n/2 + 1)
```

or

```
public int sum(int n) {
   return n/2 * (n/2 + 1);
}
```

Comment: +1 Aha , nice one ! Sum of n natural numbers :P

Comment: @Peter, +1, but worth a comment if you're being flashy with integer division with n / 2?

Comment: @Bathsheba I could have used `n >>> 1` ;)

Comment: @Peter Lawrey; showoff ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba I can't help it.  That's why I have the most Java answers ;) 8572 !!

Comment: @PeterLawrey: 8612 I guess http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:57695+[java]

Comment: @Karna SO counts tend to be cached in wonderful ways.  Have a look at the number of questions with "[java] × 439501" in the top right on this page but if you click on the `[java]` it says "442,558
questions tagged"  Still the higher number sounds better. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use following code:

```
public int sum(int n) {
  int s=0;
  for(int i=2;i<=n;i+=2){
   s+=i;
 } 
  return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   public int sum(int n)
   {
             //WRITE SOME CODE
   }
```